# A recursive sum

Tags: number-theory, summation, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let's say we start with the number one, then we add $(1/1)$. Now we have $2$. Then we do $2 + (1/2)$. Now we have $2.5$. Then we do $2.5$ plus $(1/2.5)$. If we continue this forever, I am fairly sure this diverges. However, I am wondering whether there is an implicit formula for the $n$th term of this sequence. For example: $A(1)=1$, $A(2)=2$, $A(3)=2.5$, and so on.

Comment: Each time you are adding a number greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. That should be a clue to show that this is divergent.

Comment: Thanks Neil, this is interesting. Any thoughts about an implicit function?

Comment: This has come up a number of times:  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540572/upper-bound-of-a-n1-a-n-frac1a-n),[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843014/showing-a-recursive-sequence-isnt-bounded-a-n1-a-n-frac-1-a-n),[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177111/prove-there-exists-lim-limitsn-to-inftya-n-and-find-lim-limitsn-to)